# How do I pass ExternalLoginConfirmation Model value to submitted model

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My MVC 5 project is using Facebook login. Inside `ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)` within **AccountController.cs** I parse the Facebook response to acquire the name, birthday, and email then push those values into a modified  `ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel`. That works correctly and `Model` within **ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml** contains the values such that it is displayed correctly.

My **ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml**:

```
@model itssamsbirthday.Models.ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Finalize Account";
}
<h2>Hello @Model.FirstName!</h2>
<h3>You've successfully authenticated with <strong>@ViewBag.LoginProvider</strong>.</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h4>Finalize your account below.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <p class="text-info">
        Your profile:
        <div><strong>First Name</strong>: @Model.FirstName</div>
        <div><strong>Last Name</strong>: @Model.LastName</div>
        <div><strong>Email</strong>: @Model.Email</div>
        <div><strong>Birthday</strong>: @String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", Model.BirthDate)</div>
    </p>
    <div class="text-info">
        Select the <strong>Birthday Cake</strong> that best represents you:
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProfileCake, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProfileCake, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProfileCake, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Lets Party!" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My problem is that since the other values (FirstName, LastName, Email, BirthDate) are not explicitely set using the `@Html.EditorFor(...)` within the form-group, the `model` passed to the method `ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)` is not valid where values are set to `null`. I am pretty new to HTML and MVC 5, and I do not know how to auto-pass the values of `Model` to `model` without creating the auto-generated Html forms. I imagine the solution is very simple but I cannot figure it out. I want new users to select a `ProfileCake` but everything else be automatically passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add hidden inputs for the model values you want to pass through:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName)
```